# java.io.FileNotFoundException: ~/play-2.1.1/framework/sbt/boot/update.log (No such file or directory)

Tags: java, playframework, playframework-2.0, sbt, filenotfoundexception

I wrote a Puppet to install Play 2.1.1 on Virtual Machine running CentOS 6.2.

The Puppet executed the following two commands:

```
/usr/bin/wget http://downloads.typesafe.com/play/2.1.1/play-2.1.1.zip

/usr/bin/unzip play-2.1.1.zip
```

When I run `play` command inside the package, it shows the following error message:

```
java.io.FileNotFoundException: ~/play-2.1.1/framework/sbt/boot/update.log (No such file or directory)
    at java.io.FileOutputStream.open(Native Method)
    at java.io.FileOutputStream.<init>(FileOutputStream.java:209)
    at java.io.FileOutputStream.<init>(FileOutputStream.java:160)
    at java.io.FileWriter.<init>(FileWriter.java:90)
    at xsbt.boot.Update.<init>(Checks.java:51)
    at xsbt.boot.Launch.update(Launch.scala:275)
    at xsbt.boot.Launch$$anonfun$jnaLoader$1.apply(Launch.scala:120)
    at scala.Option.getOrElse(Option.scala:108)
    at xsbt.boot.Launch.jnaLoader$2f324eef(Launch.scala:115)
    at xsbt.boot.Launch.<init>(Launch.scala:94)
    at xsbt.boot.Launcher$.apply(Launch.scala:290)
    at xsbt.boot.Launch$.apply(Launch.scala:16)
    at xsbt.boot.Boot$.runImpl(Boot.scala:31)
    at xsbt.boot.Boot$.main(Boot.scala:20)
    at xsbt.boot.Boot.main(Boot.scala)
Error during sbt execution: java.io.FileNotFoundException: ~/play-2.1.1/framework/sbt/boot/update.log (No such file or directory)
```

I didn't change a single line of code in the `play-2.1.1` directory.  I googled around for the error message, but did not find any useful answer.  Could anyone point out what is the problem?

Comment: oh, just realized this is probably a duplicate of [play framework installation](http://stackoverflow.com/q/10559313/738138).

Comment: Thanks, @gourlaysama!  The error message looks different though.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If the file does not exist and *cannot be created*,`FileOutputStream` will raise a `FileNotFoundException` (yes, this seems weird, but [see the javadoc](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/FileOutputStream.html#FileOutputStream%28java.io.File%29)).

This error probably means that the user that started play does not have the proper permissions to create `~/play-2.1.1/framework/sbt/boot/update.log` or its parent directories.

Comment: The problem is indeed that the user doesn't have proper permission to create files in the directory.